# How to ignore a java file from sonarqube inspection?

Tags: sonarqube

The sonar file in question gives false positives for duplicate blocks of code and I need to curb it at the file level. Is there any annotation or a configuration that can ignore the java class?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;  

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;        
import java.io.Serializable;        

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)        
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)        
public class SnbTransactionVo implements Serializable {            
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7178997834378189890L;            
    private Integer cellComputerNo;            
    private String tradingDate;            
    

    public Integer getCellComputerNo() {        
           return cellComputerNo;    
    }
    public void setCellComputerNo(Integer cellComputerNo) {        
           this.cellComputerNo = cellComputerNo;    
    }    
    public String getTradingDate() {        
        return tradingDate;    
    }    
    public void setTradingDate(String tradingDate) {        
        this.tradingDate = tradingDate;    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this annotation :
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:S00112")
Where squid:S00112 is the Sonar ID issue

Comment: What is the squid ID for duplicate block?

Comment: Squid ID is the is the ID of sonar issue. If you want ignore analysis files, you can use this in sonar properties : sonar.exclusions=src/java/.../youFileName or foderName